# How to hook thread creation in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Users of my application are suffering from `OutOfMemoryError`s that is possibly caused by having too many threads. Application code is carefully reviewed. A thread pool of no more than 2x of CPU core number threads is used for most background tasks. Some modules have dedicated threads for their own use, but a number of such threads are fixed and very limited. However, the application usually has 130+ threads at run-time. In a particular crash report, I even see 400+ threads running on the user's device. Since I'm using some third-party libraries in the application, I would like to investigate their behaviors. Most of the running threads are named "pool-xx-thread-1", which is the default name generated by `Executors.DefaultThreadFactory`. It seems that some library code creates a lot of single-thread pools.

How can I locate the code that creates a lot of threads?

Comment: Did you try `StrictMode` and see if it was useful? [Just realized that for main thread so probably not.]

Comment: Thank you for your edit. No, I didn't find `StrictMode` to be useful.